# Optimal way to add or remove slice element in Go without broke elements order

Tags: go

Assume I have `[]struct{}` and I need to know whether an element with `id = A` exists in the slice. If exists, the element will be removed or moved to index 0 according to request in user input. So, how to find an element in golang slice in optimal way without check each element? Or, is using `slice.contains(obj)` enough? Then, if the element exists, I will do action according to request in user input. If the request is `remove`, I will remove it without broke the elements order. But if the request is `add`, I will move the element to index 0.

Note: The function will be often called.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to write function to find element by iterating over slice:

```
func contains(s []your_struct, e int) (bool, int) {
    for idx, a := range s {
        if a.id == e {
            return true, idx
        }
    }
    return false, -1
}
```

If you a going to call the function often it may be useful to sort the slice by `id` field and implement binary search over `slice` of `your_struct`.

If the slice is not very big you can create additional data structure - `map[int]int` and keep the indexes of elements of the slice in this map. But in this case you need to synchronize content of your slice and the map when you are modifying one of them:

```
your_map := make(map[int]int)
if idx, ok := your_map[id]; ok {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But I need to keep the order of elements, so I can't sort it by id because it will broke the elements order.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check many times then
it's better to create a `map[string]int` of `id` field one time.

And every time just check map contains that `id` or not

Here,`id` as key and slice `index` as value

```
mp := make(map[string]int)
for idx, a := range yourStuctSlice {
    mp[a.id] = idx
}
if idx, ok := mp[id]; ok {
    // remove the element using idx
}
```

If new element added in slice then update the map also

```
mp[newElement.id] = true
```

If you want to remove searched element you can remove by slice index

```
func RemoveIndex(s []yourStuct, index int) []int {
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...)
}
```

```
if idx, ok := mp[id]; ok {
    yourStuctSlice = RemoveIndex(yourStuctSlice , idx)
     delete(mp , id); // Remove from map also for next search 
}
```

Comment: But if I just use `map[string]bool` with key is `id`, I can only know whether an element is exist or not. If I want to remove an element, I will search through each element again to find the element and remove it from slice. Right? I have updated my question.

Comment: If there is an update in slice, don't we need to update index in map too? So, if there is an action for next element we can do it with right index.

Comment: @RiefSapthana Yes if there is update in slice you have to update map too. Yes since you have index you can do that.